# Number theory / Group theory: consecutive integers divisible by at least n prime numbers

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

**Claim:**
There exist 15,251 successive positive integers $a_1, a_2\dots,a_{15251}$  such that
each $a_i$ where ($1\le i\le 15251$) is divisible by at least 251 different prime numbers

Is there a neat way to prove the above claim? All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.         A good system of congruences is

$x\equiv 0 \pmod{m_0}$

$x\equiv -1\pmod{m_1}$

$x\equiv -2\pmod{m_2}$

and so on up to

$x\equiv -15250\pmod{m_{15250}}$

for pairwise relatively prime $m_i$ chosen so that the divisibility by lots of primes is satisfied.

Comment: Can you please show me how to obtain successive integers this way?

Comment: Maybe it is interesting to note that $n!+1,\ldots,n!+n$is a set of successive composite integers.

Comment: @Nimbda: Let $x$ be a solution of the system of congruences, Then $m_0$ divides $x$, $m_1$ divides $x+1$, $m_2$ divides $x+2$, and so on. Note that $x,x+1,x+2,\dots$ are consecutive integers. In this particular problem, even though there is an explicit algorithm to carry out CRT, the numbers involved are far too big to actually carry out the calculation. It can be done, but requires a fair bit of computer power.

Comment: @Nimbda: Yes, we can easily produce the long string of composites $n!+2, n!+3, \dots, n!+n$. I do not see how to modify this to address the OP's "many prime divisors" problem. That's why the CRT construction.

Comment: I see, and chosing for each $m_i$ a different set of $251$ primes meets the condition.

Comment: Yes, $m_0$ can be the product of the first $251$ primes, and $m_1$ the product of the next $251$ primes, and so on.